# Is Orson Pink a descendent of Clara Oswald and Danny Pink?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Listen*, the Doctor and Clara meet Orson Pink, who, according to Clara, looks similar to Danny Pink. (Both Danny and Orson are played by Samuel Anderson.)

Another clue is Orson mentioning about his great-grandparents telling "silly stories" about time travel. Also, the Doctor and Clara manage to reach Orson's location using the telepathic circuits of TARDIS.

At first, this scene gives an idea that Clara and Danny marry and have children that in a future generation would give birth to Orson Pink. Then, in the Series 8 finale episodes, Danny Pink "dies" and, when given the chance to come back to the real world, sends the Afghan boy Danny kills in a war (possibly the 2001 War in Afghanistan?) to Clara, potentially killing the idea that Orson is related to Danny and Clara.

But the question remains: is Orson Pink a descendent of Clara Oswald and Danny Pink?

Comment: *Also, the Doctor and Clara manage to reach Orson's location using the telepathic circuits of TARDIS.* Don't forget that they also reach the young Danny as well as the young Doctor; both not being directly relatives to Clara in any way (at least so far...).

Comment: @Mario The idea being that the telepathic circuits followed what she was thinking about.  It led her to young Danny because there is a connection, and she was thinking about him, not because they are related.  It was certainly heavily implied that Orson was the descendant of Danny and Clara.

Comment: @DaveJohnson True, but how could she "think" about Orson? Let's assume she's been pregnant and thought about the baby, I'd say they should have arrived in the near future - not somewhere else at the location of some grand-grand-whatever-children.

Comment: @Mario Obviously she was still thinking about Danny, and made it to one of his descendants.  "The navigation system is knackered."

Comment: Rule #1, the Moffat lies.

Comment: Please put the info from Moffat into an answer; don't edit that into your question.

Comment: My guess is that on the Christmas special they will save Danny.

Comment: Oh, by the way, which one's Pink? :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The answer is inconclusive.

If the timeline is to be believed and is indeed correct, there are two possible solutions:

> Danny Pink is somehow recovered from the Nethersphere and returned to life. This is unlikely give the circumstances. He appeared to give up his one chance to return to life by sending the young boy in his place.

OR

> Clara is pregnant and will indeed bear offspring who will in time, tell tales of time travel and meet the Doctor and their ancestor, Clara in the future. Observe the sticky note that says 3 months... What could that mean? (Was their relationship only three months? Or could it mean something else?)

[image: Screencap of post it notes with names on them]

Since the finale just aired, it may be some time before we know which answer will be the correct one.

---

**Moffat has recently [weighed in and his official word](http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/moffat-on-orson-pink-mystery-69591.htm) is the possibility of another family member who may have been given the toy soldier in the future. We are given no further enlightenment so the verdict may never truly be resolved.**

> “I can think of several explanations, but the obvious one is that Orson comes from another branch of the family. He knows about Danny’s heroic sacrifice, because Clara got in touch with the Pink family after the events of Death in Heaven (because you would, wouldn’t you?), and told them what he did, and why. And she gave them the little soldier, as a keepsake of a great man and a great soldier – and because she knows the toy soldier has to remain in the Pink family line.
>
> “Now all that strikes me as pretty inevitable – that’s what would have happened – but I’m not saying it’s right. Nothing is actual till it’s in the show. Knowing how the season would end, we were careful, in never to define exactly what the connection was.”

Comment: or neither of the above occurs. "Time can be rewritten". Perhaps meeting Orson Pink in the future is just one of those "timey wimey" anomalies that theoretically shouldn't have been possible now Danny is dead.

Comment: Possibility three: Those stories might originate from Danny only and Clara isn't any relative at all.

Comment: When Clara rings Danny at the beginning of the season 8 finale, one of the sticky notes suggests your 2nd point may be correct.

Comment: @Adeptus What did the sticky note say that suggests that Clara might be pregnant? Is it the sticky note that says "Three Months"?  https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/photo-17-copy-5-e1415560993894.png?w=768&h=429&crop=1#038;h=568

Comment: @GrrHackPrecioussss Yes that's the one. Some fans think that's what it's implying. They could be entirely wrong, of course.

Comment: @Adeptus It did take about three months to show Series 8 in its entirety. Coincidence? Maybe. Nonetheless, the sticky note might be a clue.

Comment: I notice Robin Hood gets two sticky notes. Could the baby be his?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: Maybe bringing Danny back is going to be Clara's christmas present from Santa? ;)

Comment: @Adeptus maybe for one night only ifyouknowwhatimean?

Comment: Oh thanks, now I'm even more scaried from potentially watching the christmas episode, fearing an even more horrible plot twist. *dum dum duuuum*

Comment: Steven Moffat has weighed in on the matter in the December issue of Doctor Who Magazine. (see the update to the question and http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/moffat-on-orson-pink-mystery-69591.htm)

Comment: Danny somehow gets two futures? You know, timey wimey ball...

Comment: Both your solutions are now excluded, since Clara is basically out of the game. Not exactly dead, but on her last heartbeat...

Answer (score 3):

Steven Moffat provides his opinion regarding Orson Pink's ancestors in the [December 2014 issue of Doctor Who Magazine](http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/moffat-on-orson-pink-mystery-69591.htm). It appears that Orson Pink may not be a direct descendant of Clara's offspring, but rather a descendant of the offspring from another branch of the Pink family.

> “I can think of several explanations, but the obvious one is that Orson comes from another branch of the family. He knows about Danny’s heroic sacrifice, because Clara got in touch with the Pink family after the events of Death in Heaven (because you would, wouldn’t you?), and told them what he did, and why. And she gave them the little soldier, as a keepsake of a great man and a great soldier – and because she knows the toy soldier has to remain in the Pink family line.
>
> “Now all that strikes me as pretty inevitable – that’s what would have happened – but I’m not saying it’s right. Nothing is actual till it’s in the show. Knowing how the season would end, we were careful, in never to define exactly what the connection was.”

Of course, Moffat may be lying to us.

Comment: Moffat's never lied before though, surely? :D

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for Clara to have had a child with Danny Pink because (spoiler alert) after Danny dies, Clara still continues to travel with the doctor (if she had a kid don't you think it would have been mentioned or maybe she would have been more careful or not traveled as much?) up until the point at which she dies in front of the doctor. She is then taken out of the moments right before her death, but does not have a pulse. She is frozen in time and basically still dead. Then she goes back in a stolen Tardis with whats her face (the stupid one that amazingly stayed alive through everything??? wtf) to go back to the moment before her death and fix time. She travels along the way, but even then, she couldn't have a child because she was basically dead. Dead people can't have alive children with a dead guy.

Comment: I wouldn't say *impossible*.  Clara may have been left with her biological processes halted, but there's no certainty that will continue for ever.  She has a TARDIS (and, apparently, knows how to use it).  She's with "Me" who has a history of not exactly following the rules.  She's resourceful.  She may be planning on returning to Gallifrey to surrender -- eventually -- but who knows what she'll do on the way, or what she might find out about her situation?

Comment: Quite a bit of time passes for both Clara & the Doctor between episodes. They each live their lives separate from one another. Plenty of time for Clara to have given birth, since we don't know how much "apart" time they have between when we see them together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Orson Pink could be a descendant of an alternate version of Clara created when Clara entered the Doctor's timeline on Trenzalore. Through either at least a one nighter with Danny or a relationship with another relative of Danny’s from the time that version of Clara is from had a baby that would lead to Orson Pink.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that led you to this theory that you could [edit] in?

Comment: Honestly it’s just a thought

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Clara already has the baby but isn't born yet and Danny is the father.  There is a sticky note that says, "Three Months" and maybe she's had it for that amount of time, in the episode, Clara could have been wanting to tell Danny about it maybe that's what the sticky note was for.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) .. I think this sound more like a comment.

Comment: In the Steven Moffat universe, everything is wibbly wobbly timey wimey. :)